# A iOS crash that doesn't have enough clue to fix. SIGSEGV crash at _objc_msgSend

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

I met a crash and I have no idea how to solve it. It is a SIGSEGV crash, and here is the last code stack:

```
0
libobjc.A.dylib
_objc_msgSend + 44
1
CoreFoundation
-[__NSSetI containsObject:] + 156
2
UIKitCore
-[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:] + 3532
3
UIKitCore
-[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 160
4
UIKitCore
-[UIInputResponderController forceReloadInputViews] + 220
5
UIKitCore
___43-[_UIRemoteKeyboards reloadForSnapshotting]_block_invoke + 148
6
UIKitCore
+[UIInputResponderController performOnControllers:] + 476
7
UIKitCore
-[_UIRemoteKeyboards setIsSnapshotting:] + 108
8
UIKitCore
-[UITextEffectsWindow _willSnapshot] + 124
9
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:] + 776
10
UIKitCore
___65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
11
UIKitCore
-[UIScene _enableOverrideSettingsForActions:] + 60
12
UIKitCore
-[UIScene _performSystemSnapshotWithActions:] + 120
13
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:] + 440
14
UIKitCore
___98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_3 + 168
15
UIKitCore
___98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 468
16
UIKitCore
-[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 664
17
UIKitCore
-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 220
18
UIKitCore
-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 464
19
FrontBoardServices
-[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 456
20
FrontBoardServices
___94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 124
21
FrontBoardServices
-[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
22
FrontBoardServices
___94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 368
23
libdispatch.dylib
__dispatch_client_callout + 16
24
libdispatch.dylib
__dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
25
FrontBoardServices
___FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
26
FrontBoardServices
-[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
27
FrontBoardServices
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
28
CoreFoundation
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
29
CoreFoundation
___CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
30
CoreFoundation
___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 356
31
CoreFoundation
___CFRunLoopRun + 776
32
CoreFoundation
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
33
GraphicsServices
_GSEventRunModal + 160
34
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _run] + 1052
35
UIKitCore
_UIApplicationMain + 164
36
LetvIphoneClient
main (main.m:29)
37
libdyld.dylib
_start + 4
```

Other information:

1. this crash mostly appear at the launching of the App.
2. read the code stack, the crash probably takes place when user's keyboard is using.

I can't solve this crash because I don't have enough clues and the code stack doesn't have any my App code, only system code.

Any clue about this crash is appreciate. Thank you.

What's interesting thing is, this crash takes place on time everyday, just 5pm to 8pm(Beijing time). We can not see any one crash takes place at other time in a day. A weird crash!

Comment: Check  storyboard/xib presence in app, check for network. These are some clues found on SO. Try to make a minimal reproducible project from your app .

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks. But We NEVER reproduce this crash. We see this crash in our crash system like Crashlytics/Fabric. So, it is a hard work.

Comment: Did you tried to use a remote keyboard ?

Comment: @PtitXav You mean a Bluetooth keyboard to control iPhone?